# jquery mobile ajax always GET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am using a jquery mobile for mobile application, and I try to reuse as much as possible of the original desktop app.  So, one of my pagers has ajax links and uses HttpPost PartialViewResult method.

I have two methods that are named the same way, but one is HttpPost and second one is regular. When I debug with firebug I see that all the links in the pager are being sent with HttpGet even though I specify the `post` type. Code for ajax options:

```
var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions { 
    UpdateTargetId = "productList", 
    HttpMethod = "POST", 
    OnBegin = "beginPaging", 
    OnSuccess = "endPaging", 
    OnFailure = "errorPaging" 
};
```

Basically my questions is, why ajax calls are always GET, and how can I change that. Thank you. I am using MVC3 if it helps.

Comment: Did you include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page?

Comment: that was it! Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: There is another problem now. The link does HttpGet first and then HttpPost after that. Should I create a new question?

Comment: answer posted. As far as the second problem is concerned, yes, you should post another question but you will have to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page. This script unobtrusively AJAXifies anchors and forms generated with the Ajax.* helpers.